# Iterating through a dictionary for a specific outcome

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iteration

I have a dictionary in which the keys represent the categories and their values the item-lists for each category, like so:

```py
d = {category_a: [item_a, item_b, item_c], category_b: [item_d, item_e]}
```

I want to iterate through the dictionary for the following result:

```
category_a
· item_a
· item_b
· item_c
category_b
· item_d
· item_e
```

The formatting with break-lines and such seem to work. My issue is that I only get to the following result:

```
category_a
· item_a
· item_b
· item_c
· item_d
· item_e
category_b
· item_a
· item_b
· item_c
· item_d
· item_e
```

I understand that my code (see below) iterates though all items for all keys, which probably causes the issue. Everything else have I tried leads to errors or one-letter-per-line outcome. I want to place the outcome in a PySimpleGUI Multiline. That's why I intend to place it in a string.

Here is my basic code-structure:

```py
def display():

    d = {category_a: [item_a, item_b, item_c], category_b: [item_d, item_e]}
    
    output = ""

    for k in d.keys():
        output += k + "\n"

        for key, val in d.items():
            for v in val:
                output += " · " + v + "\n"

    return output
```

I tried, in the second for loop, to only access the values of the key used above (first loop) but can't get it working: Either I only get the item-list - not the items in it - or I produce an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected code:

```
def display():

    d = {'category_a': ['item_a', 'item_b', 'item_c'], 'category_b': ['item_d', 'item_e']}
    
    output = ""

    for k in d.keys():    # for k in d:  also works
        output += k + "\n"
        for v in d[k]:
            output += " · " + v + "\n"

    return output
```

Comment: The issue in your code is you are iterating through each keys in first for-loop and in the nested for-loop you are again iterating through the key-value pairs in the dictionary. So for each keys, you are iterating all the values instead of iterating through the corresponding value. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can call method `print` of `Multiline` element directly.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def display(ml):
    d = {
        "category_a": ["item_a", "item_b", "item_c"],
        "category_b": ["item_d", "item_e"],
    }
    for key, items in d.items():
        ml.print(key)
        for item in items:
            ml.print(f". {item}")

sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12, "bold"))
layout = [[sg.Multiline("", size=(40, 10), key='-ML-')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
display(window['-ML-'])
window.read(close=True)
```

[image]

Comment: So much to like about this answer.... the call to `Multiline. print`, the formatting of the text, and the simplicity are great.  I sometimes drop a font parameter into the `Window` call for this kind of window so a call to `set_options` isn't needed... but sometimes you want a font to apply to popups too and the code above will do that so it's not unreasonable to take this approach.  

Answer (score 0):

```py
def display():

    d = {"category_a": ["item_a", "item_b", "item_c"], "category_b": ["item_d", "item_e"]}
    
    output = ""

    for k,v in d.items():
        output += k + "\n"
        for val in v:
            output += " · " + val + "\n"
    return output
```

The value of the `dict` is a `list`, so just iterate though the `list`

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps.
Keep the good work!

```
def display():
    d = {"category_a": ["item_a", "item_b", "item_c"], "category_b": ["item_d", "item_e"]}

    output = ""
    for key, val in d.items():
        output += key + "\n"
        for v in val:
            output += " · " + v + "\n"
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(display())
```

Comment: Why *for k in d.keys()* ?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of making multiple calls to *print()* rather build a list of what needs to be printed. Something like this:

```
def display(d):
    out = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        out.append(k)
        out += [f' · {_v}' for _v in v]
    print(*out, sep='\n')

d = {'category_a': ['item_a', 'item_b', 'item_c'], 'category_b': ['item_d', 'item_e']}

display(d)
```

**Output:**

```
category_a
 · item_a
 · item_b
 · item_c
category_b
 · item_d
 · item_e
```